# Can anyone find the password in this sfw code?

Tags: flash

First of all, this is not for something illegal. I'm simply trying to find the password for secretprojects.com completely out of curiosity. I know it's a long code, but I hope someone with a bit more flash knowledge can find the password for the site. Thank you.

Didn't want to paste the whole code, so here's a link:
http://www.showmycode.com/?b0b0462584bd0d14e9a5cd0740644a2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is loaded from an XML file that is located at http://secretprojects.com/config.xml. At the current moment it is `scrt:proj3ctum`